# How to pass an attribute instead of the selected value in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, attributes, attr

I would like to pass the email attribute in the testEmail variable but it is passing the name `John Doe`

```
<option value="2" email="test@email.com">John Doe</option>
```

```
var testEmail = $("#nameofDropdown option:selected").text();
var email = promt("Enter an email to send to", testEmail );
```

I know it has to do with this line `option:selected` just not sure what to change it to to get the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.attr()` rather than `.text()`

```
$("#nameofDropdown option:selected").attr('email')
```

```js
console.log($("option").attr('email'));
```

```html
<option value="2" email="test@email.com">John Doe</option>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```